# RSpec + Autotest Error on Mac OS X

Tags: rspec, rubygems, autotest

I'm trying to run the command 'bundle exec autotest' in Terminal. I can get RSpec working if I use 'bundle exec rspec spec/', but I can't get autotest (the first command) running. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Trenton-Scotts-MacBook-Air:sample_app TTS$ bundle exec autotestloading autotest/rails_rspec2
/Users/TTS/Documents/Rails/sample_app/.autotest:1:in `require': no such file to load -- autotest/growl (LoadError)
    from /Users/TTS/Documents/Rails/sample_app/.autotest:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/ZenTest-4.4.2/lib/autotest.rb:305:in `load'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/ZenTest-4.4.2/lib/autotest.rb:305:in `block in initialize'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/ZenTest-4.4.2/lib/autotest.rb:304:in `each'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/ZenTest-4.4.2/lib/autotest.rb:304:in `initialize'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rspec-core-2.4.0/lib/autotest/rspec2.rb:10:in `initialize'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rspec-rails-2.4.1/lib/autotest/rails_rspec2.rb:31:in `initialize'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/ZenTest-4.4.2/lib/autotest.rb:236:in `new'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/ZenTest-4.4.2/lib/autotest.rb:236:in `run'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/ZenTest-4.4.2/bin/autotest:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/autotest:19:in `load'
    from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/autotest:19:in `<main>'
```

I have two lines in .autotest in my Rails project folder:

```
require 'autotest/growl'
require 'autotest/fsevent'
```

I installed the gems for autotest-growl and autotest-fsevent. My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.4.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.4.0'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it! The correct command is 'autotest', not 'bundle exec autotest'. 'rspec spec/' also works too.

Answer (score 0):

Trenton I solved that issue putting all gems executables under /bin with `bundle install --binstubs` and including growl on **Gemfile**. I don't know why autotest gem did not created any executable after execute `gem install autotest`. In which directory do you have that executable?